# Do I have to put the article 'the' in this sentence?

Tags: articles, definite-article

> When the priest stepped into the church, all (the) worshipers attending rose from their seats.

Do I have to put the article 'the' in this sentence?

I know the general rule about the difference between 'all + object' and 'all the + object'—the first referring to all of that object in the world or in general, the second about a more specific set. But after doing several searches on ngram, I found many cases that turned out to be quite tricky. And in a forum, I found a similar sentence corrected by native English speaker in two different ways, i.e. with AND without the article, which left me rather confused.

Comment: You are talking about a particular group of people (those present in the church), so _the_ is appropriate. (BTW, I would say _rose from their seats_ as they had one each!)

Comment: not attending people. people attending or attendees, but people in church are worshipers.

Comment: You don't *have* to, no. It's optional. However, it would be a lot more common in that particular construction to include it.